# Corner Radius Not Working?

Tags: css, swift

im trying to setup a circle image view and when I set the corner radius to perform the operation it does absolutely nothing. I've looked at various threads and solutions none worked

```
import UIKit

class AlterProfileViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigationItem.title = "Profile Settings"
    view.addSubview(selectProfileImage)


    ///Constraints for all views will go here

    _ = selectProfileImage.anchor(view.centerYAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: -275, leftConstant: 135, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 100, heightConstant: 100)

  //  selectProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = selectProfileImage.frame.size.width/2

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//Where all buttons and labels will be added

//will just be a nice looking image view to be next to the profile settings button
lazy var selectProfileImage: UIImageView = {
    let selectPicture = UIImageView()
   // self.selectProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.selectProfileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
    selectPicture.image = UIImage(named: "Paris")

    // selectPicture.layer.cornerRadius = selectPicture.frame.size.width / 2;
    selectPicture.clipsToBounds = true
    selectPicture.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    selectPicture.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    selectPicture.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    selectPicture.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return selectPicture
}()

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



}
```

None of the methods seem to work im actually kind of stumped right now

Comment: add  selectPicture.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you layout with AutoLayout I would suspect the image view simply doesn't have the correct size when you calculate the radius. The image view is initialized with a size of `0,0` and thus the calculated radius will be `0` as well. Instead, move the radius calculation in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` after calling super:

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    selectProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = selectProfileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
    selectProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: @HiDungLing please note that if this is the desired answer to your question, you should accept it (green tick).